# Document similarity with doc2vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

With this Gensim example in github, https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb it provides examples at the end to find simalarities with phrases or keywords, like 'lady gaga' or 'machine learning'. However am looking to find similarity with actual document in plain text file, could this be done? and how can I do it? suppose text file is located on my local laptop in txt format.

Comment: Yes can be done by using lda from gensim package itself

Comment: but dont want lda, i need doc2vec similarity

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the  you just need to change `wiki = WikiCorpus("enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2")` to your text file path!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenize the query-document the same as the training data. Pass those tokens to the `Doc2Vec` model's `infer_vector()` method to get a vector for the query-document. Pass that vector to `most_similar()` to get a ranked list of known documents similar to that vector.

There are examples of using `infer_vector()` this way in cells 10 and forward in another demo notebook included with `gensim`:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know how to tokenize the query-document (text file)? please help

Comment: Use the same code as was used to tokenize any training documents. (If all that was done was `.split()` on whitespace, that might be enough. But if other case-flattening, word-dropping, etc was applied to training data, then apply it to the query-document as well.)

Comment: If you have specifically built your model as per that `doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb` notebook, using the `WikiCorpus` class in `gensim`, take a look at the `preprocess_text()` method in that class, it might do what you need: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.html#gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.WikiCorpus.preprocess_text

Comment: Thanks @gojomo but now am having problem with this notebook, I get the error _AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'scan_vocab'_ when I use this 'pre.scan_vocab(documents)' is there similar attribute for doc2vec replaces _(scan_vocab)_?

Comment: It's possible other refactoring in recent `gensim` versions broke that line of the notebook. Unless you need to optimize `min_count` to reach a specific vocabulary-size, you can skip those cells [5]-[6]. And even if you do want a specific surviving vocabulary size, there's a new `max_final_vocab` parameter you can use instead.

Comment: I finally made that work but I get stuck 'models[0].build_vocab(documents)' , I get memory error running it on Jupyter after 5 hours!

Comment: Then, you need more memory, and/or to ensure your corpus handling isn't using too much memory, and/or to choose model parameters that use less memory during vocabulary-scanning and post-scan model-initialization. (Enabling INFO logging could clarify when the error is hit; there's a good chance it's after the full scan, when the model arrays for all discovered/surviving words/doctags are allocated.)

Comment: thanks, am at the end of the journey when i run this cell                               **for model in models:
    print((model))
    pprint(model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"], topn=20))**                                                                                                              i get this error: **ypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'** pointing to pprint

Comment: That seems like a separate question/problem that could be posted with the full coe to-to-trigger and error stack, if you're still struggling with it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130738/gensim-example-typeerrorbetween-str-and-int-error]