# Gensim example, TypeError:between str and int error

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

When running the below code. this Python 3.6, latest Gensim library in Jupyter

```
for model in models:
       print(str(model))
       pprint(model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=["Machine learning"], topn=20))
```

[1]: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb[image]

Comment: please provide
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted has other, unrelated errors (f.e. no `form pprint import pprint`) - unlcear what models are etc

Comment: @patrick arther, here is the code: https://github.com/jqadan/word_vectors_game_of_thrones-LIVE/blob/master/wiki_train.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for providing your _full code_. SO strifes to create a lookup repository for ppl having the same problem as you do, coming here in 5monts, 2 years , ... Therefor you should minimize the code to a MVCE (see link above) that is fully present in your question. If github goes bankrupt and its server get disconnected,your sources there are no longer accessable and ppl coming to this questions can't comprehend your problem. I am unfamilar with gensim - others might take a peek but will be discouraged if they have to follow links to code.

Comment: One thing you might want to check though, if you use `print ("a" < 5)` in python 2.7 this will be valid code and get you `False`.  In python 3.6 as you are using it, if give you this exact error. Same if you do `s = sorted( ["a",5])` - valid in 2.7, Error in 3.6. You seem to have some mixed data thats being categorized by the internal mechanics of `model.docvecs.most_similar(...)` which would work in 2.7 but does not in 3.6. You should investigate in that direction.

Comment: You should try to be sure whatever code excerpts you do provide are properly indented, and also quote the *full* error stack to be clear where the error is occurring.

Comment: @gojomo edited and added error message. thanks.

Comment: You should include the full error stack as copied-and-pasted text, *not* an image-of-text, so that it can be better indexed and similarity-matched, or copied-and-pasted by answerers looking for supporting material. Images-of-text are very reader- and reuse- hostile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string= "machine learning".split()

doc_vector = model.infer_vector(string)
out= model.docvecs.most_similar([doc_vector])
```

I'm not sure 100% since I'm using a more recent release, but I think that the issue is connected to the fact that the most_similar function is expecting a string mapped in the feature space and not the raw string.

Comment: Thanks @Roberto this worked, but applied to text8 corpus, however I dont get most similar titles, instead i get a rusult of vector [212, 0.44, 198, 0.37 etc] how can I check what are the titles for these indexes.

Comment: @JayQadan the function is outputting a list of tuples indicating (index, degree of similarity)-> index is the index of the most similar document in your corpora, the "degree of similarity" is how similar is your query to the document. In order to retrieve the original text I suggest you to store the document that you use for the training before any kind of preprocessing. using the outputted index you can retrieve the original text. i know that it's a pain. 
Please if you have found useful my first answer signal it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `'Machine learning'` is not a known tag in your model. (Maybe your model knows `'machine learning'` or `'machine_learning'` or some other such?)

It's harder to recognize that's the real issue, because of a poor error message from the code in this case. It's a known issue at the `gensim` project:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1737

Comment: I tried other words, phrases,  combination of keywords,  I keep getting same error. I used 2.7python, but I ran to other errors when training the model!

Comment: If you keep getting the same error, your model includes none of the document tags you're trying. Something likely went wrong during training. Did you enable `INFO`-level logging and look for suspicious output, like durations or counts-of-words/tags that seemed wrong? What does `len(model.docvecs)` return?